# "Resolve" functions in JavaScript promises

Tags: javascript, constructor, promise

I am reading this documentation about how to use promises, and frequently "resolve" and "reject" are passed in as arguments to the Promise constructor, even though nobody ever defined the "resolve" or "reject" functions.  How is that possible?  Don't we have to define functions before using them?

Here's an example: (source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Browser_compatibility)

```
var p1 = new Promise(
        // The resolver function is called with the ability to resolve or
        // reject the promise
        function(resolve, reject) {
            log.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', thisPromiseCount +
                ') Promise started (<small>Async code started</small>)<br/>');
            // This only is an example to create asynchronism
            window.setTimeout(
                function() {
                    // We fulfill the promise !
                    resolve(thisPromiseCount);
                }, Math.random() * 2000 + 1000);
        });
```

Comment: In the code you posted, `resolve` and `reject` are the formal function parameters. Nothing is being *passed* anywhere; it's the *definition* of a function and those are the names of the parameters. When the function is actually *called*, those will refer to functions that will have been defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

They are not passed in as arguments *to* the `Promise` constructor.

They are passed as arguments *by* the `Promise` constructor into your `resolver` callback function that declares them as *parameters*.

This is similar to the parameters of other callbacks, for example

```
array.sort(function(a, b) { … })
//                  ^  ^
array.map(function(element, index) { … })
//                 ^^^^^^^  ^^^^^
```

only that the values are functions in the case of the `Promise` constructor callback.

Comment: Hm, I'd bet this is a duplicate but I cant find any.